# New Instance from dll

Tags: c#

I have a windows application. I added another application's dll to it's reference.
second application has a Form named MainForm. 
I want to create a new instance from that dll and run MainForm from it?
Is it possible? if yes, How can i do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Please read: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Yes, no problem.  Of course you'll have to edit the Program.cs file and change the code there so that it creates an instance of your other form class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
using Project2; // Or whatever.

...

Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

? If that doesn't help, you'll need to give more information.

Comment: but I get this exception: Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.